# Authenticating to Github reppository with Username and Password credentials in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, authentication, github, jenkins-pipeline

I have created a Multibranch pipeline on Jenkins 2.107.2. I want to perform Git commands like `git commit`, `git push` etc on the cloned repository.

To authenticate to the GitHub repository, I have configured my user credentials in Jenkins using (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin). I have tried few approaches to use these credentials to authenticate but they result in different errors.

**First Approach**

```
stage('clone'){
        steps{
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/develop']],
 userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com:xyz/demo.git']]])
        }
    }
stage('prepare release'){
        steps{
            sh "sed -i 's/-SNAPSHOT//g' pom.xml"
            withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'jenkins-user-for-demo-github', usernameVariable: 'GITHUB_DEMO_CREDENTIALS_USR', passwordVariable: 'GITHUB_DEMO_CREDENTIALS_PSW']]) {
                sh "git add pom.xml"
                sh "git commit -m 'release version set"
            }
        }
    }
```

Error

> *** Please tell me who you are.
>    Run
>    git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
>    git config --global user.name "Your Name"

**Second Approach**

```
stage('Checkout') {
        steps{
            git branch: 'develop', credentialsId: 'jenkins-user-for-demo-github', url: 'git@github.com:xyz/demo.git'
        }
    }
stage('prepare release'){
        steps{
            sh "sed -i 's/-SNAPSHOT//g' pom.xml"
            sh "git add pom.xml"
            sh "git commit -m 'release version set"
        }
    }
```

Error

> Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:AbhayChandel/New-project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
>   stdout: 
>   stderr: Host key verification failed.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

Struggling with these errors I have following questions:

1. Is it possible to pass Username & Password credentials for authentication to Github repository from Jenkinsfile?
2. Should I use SSH key instead of Username & Password?
3. Is there any other approach I should try(but not too hackish)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Credentials" are only required for talking to the Git server (e.g. `git clone`, `git fetch`, `git push`) but **NOT** for manipulating the local repository. So in your first example git does **not** complain about **credentials** but about missing **configuration** when doing `git commit`. You can set arbitrary stuff here like this:

```
stage('clone'){
    steps{
      checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/develop']], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com:xyz/demo.git']]])
      sh "git config user.name 'John Doe'"
      sh "git config user.email 'foo@bar.bla'"
    }
}
```

After that the `git commit` should work. And unless you want to push the commit you can remove the `withCredentials` wrapper.