# user.name and user.email aren't properly passed when running PreBuildMerge on slave/container

Tags: git, authentication, jenkins, credentials, git-config

I'm running jobs on Jenkins which utilizes both nodes and containers so different teams don't use each other's resources. It works fine except for a single job that is supposed to handle .jar files creation. It uses PreBuildMerge class during checkout and I've isolated it as a source of the problem. That's how the code looks like:

```
    checkout([
            $class                           : 'GitSCM',
            branches                         : [[name: "${env.FROM_BRANCH}"]],
            browser                          : [$class : 'Stash',
                                                repoUrl: "${settings['data_load_repo']}"],
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
            extensions                       : [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'],
                                                [$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: "${env.TO_BRANCH}"],
                                                [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: "${targetProjectDirName}"],
                                                [$class             : 'SubmoduleOption',
                                                 disableSubmodules  : false,
                                                 parentCredentials  : true,
                                                 recursiveSubmodules: false,
                                                 reference          : '',
                                                 trackingSubmodules : false],
                                                [$class : 'PreBuildMerge',
                                                 options: [fastForwardMode: 'NO_FF',
                                                           mergeRemote    : 'origin',
                                                           mergeStrategy  : 'DEFAULT',
                                                           mergeTarget    : env.TO_BRANCH]]],
            submoduleCfg                     : [],
            userRemoteConfigs                : [[credentialsId: settings['bb_credentials_id'], url: "${settings['data_load_repo']}"]]
    ])
}
```

Everytime it ends with error:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'jenkins@dce20-aem-rollout-r3w27.(none)')
```

I've already tried to set those values- both with git commands and writing directly to both .gitconfig and .git/config files, I've also set them under "additional behaviors" in job config- there's no difference, I still get same error message. By experimenting with code I've found two things:
-removing code written below makes job run ok (but it's not a solution as it needs to be premerged):

```
[$class : 'PreBuildMerge',
                                                 options: [fastForwardMode: 'NO_FF',
                                                           mergeRemote    : 'origin',
                                                           mergeStrategy  : 'DEFAULT',
                                                           mergeTarget    : env.TO_BRANCH]]
```

-job runs just fine when started on master rather than container running on slave.

I've no idea how to proceed with this issue, there doesn't seem to be any way to pass user.name and user.email when running PreBuildMerge which doesn't work at all.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55108199/authenticating-to-github-reppository-with-username-and-password-credentials-in-j ?

Comment: I just did and tried adding commands according to answer but it didn't work and I'm not surprised- my problem is not lack of configuration itself- checkout progresses just fine until PreBuildMerge kick in. Before it does both user.name and user.email are configured and can be accessed with sh 'git config --global -l' Only when PBM attempts to perform merge it cannot find them. It's as if it's trying to access configuration in different place then GitSCM did.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work via the UserIdentity Git Jenkins extension. Here's my pipeline script that got this to work:

```
stages {
    stage('Clone') {
        steps {
            dir('src') {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: sha1]],
                    extensions: [
                        // We have to set an idenity for the merge step because Git requires
                        // the user.name and user.email to be set to do a merge.
                        [$class: "UserIdentity",
                            name: "Some User",
                            email: "some_user@some.where.com"
                        ],
                        [$class: "PreBuildMerge",
                            options: [
                                mergeTarget: "master",
                                fastForwardMode: "FF",
                                mergeRemote: "origin"                                ]
                        ],
                    ],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: github_url, refspec: '+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*']]])
            }
        }
    }
```

---

By the way, I too am a user, and I find this stuff isn't really documented extensively. For instance, where is the `UserIdentity` extension documented for how to set it up in a Pipeline script? Maybe it's there and I just can't find it. If you want to figure out the details and you can read source code, it's not too bad to piece things together from the source:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git

Here's the UserIdentity extension, for instance:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/extensions/impl/UserIdentity.java